# Can't get antialiasing with SVG & D3.JS

Tags: svg, d3.js, rendering, antialiasing

I am using D3JS to draw a graph and facing the following problem. All circles, just lines are rendered properly using antialiasing, however path for some reasons has stairs effect.

Could you please point what is wrong? 
Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/DV6Ba/
My CSS doesn't have any crispEdges:

```
.v-path {
    stroke-width: 1.0px;

    fill: none;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem. D3 js was generating multiple lines on top of each other, and so even though they were antialiased, they were overlapping and increase the antialising effect so it looked like non-antialiased.

Comment: And how to fix it?